# Seeking advice on numerical solutions for a quadrotor soft landing optimization control problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis

I am working on an optimization control problem concerning the soft landing of a quadrotor. The dynamic model and performance index are given as follows:

Its dynamic model is:
$$\dot{r}=v$$
$$\dot{v}=c_1\frac{u_1}{m}\widehat{i_\theta}+g$$
$$\dot{\theta}=c_{2}u_{2}$$
$$r=\left(x,z\right)$$
$$v=\left(v_x,v_z\right)$$

Performance index:
$$J=\left(1-\alpha\right)\int_{0}^{t_f}\left(\gamma_1c_1^2u_1^2+\gamma_2c_2^2u_2^2\right)dt+\alpha\int_{0}^{t_f}dt$$

Terminal constraint
$$r_t=\left(0,0\right),v_t=\left(0,0\right)$$
Known conditions
$$g=9.8m/s^2$$
$$u_{1}\in\left[0.05,1\right]$$
$$i_\theta=\left[sin\theta,cos\theta\right]$$
$$c_{1}=20N\left(0.05c_{1}=1N\right)$$
$$u_{2}\in\left[-1,1\right]$$
$$c_{2}=2rad/s$$

Since I'm not familiar with handling vectors, I'll convert the problem  as follows:
Let
$$x_{1} =x$$
$$x_{2}=\dot{x_{1}}$$
$$x_{3}=z$$
$$x_{4}=\dot{x_{3}}$$
$$x_{5} =\theta$$
State equation
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\dot{x_{1}}=x_{2}  \\\dot{x_{2}}=20\frac{u_{1}}{m}sinx_{5}  \\\dot{x_{3}}=x_{4} \\\dot{x_{4}}=20\frac{u_{1}}{m}cos_{5}+9.8 \\\dot{x_{5}}=2u_{2}\end{matrix}\right.$$
Initial conditions

$$x_{1}\left ( 0 \right ) = 50$$
$$x_{2}(0 )=0$$
$$x_{3}(0 ) = 50$$
$$x_{4}(0 )=0$$
$$x_{5}(0 )=0$$
Boundary conditions
$$x_{1}(t_{f}) =0$$
$$x_{2}(t_{f}) =0$$
$$x_{3}(t_{f})=0$$
$$x_{4}(t_{f})=0$$
$$x_{5}(t_{f}) =0$$
Constrained control
$$0.05\le u_{1} \le 1$$
$$-1\le u_{2} \le 1$$

Performance index
$$J=\left(1-\alpha\right)\int_{0}^{t_f}\left(\gamma_1c_1^2u_1^2+\gamma_2c_2^2u_2^2\right)dt+\alpha\int_{0}^{t_f}dt$$

My attempt to solve this problem involved the Hamiltonian, but I encountered difficulties when dealing with the trigonometric functions in the costate equations. Specifically, I was unable to solve for λ5 due to the presence of these functions.

The issue lies here:

Specifically, as follows:
$$\varphi (\bullet )=\alpha t_{f}$$

$$L (\bullet )=\left(1-\alpha\right)\left(\gamma_1c_1^2u_1^2+\gamma_2c_2^2u_2^2\right)$$

Hamiltonian
$$H (\bullet )=\left(1-\alpha\right)\left(\gamma_1c_1^2u_1^2+\gamma_2c_2^2u_2^2\right)+\lambda _{1}x_{2}+\lambda _{2}\frac{20u_{1}}{m}sinx_{5}+\lambda _{3}x_{4}+\lambda _{4}(\frac{20u_{1}}{m}cosx_{5} +9.8)+\lambda _{5}\times 2u_{2}$$

Next, solve by the general optimization method. From the costate equation, we have

$$\dot{\lambda _{1}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{1}} =0,so \lambda _{1} = c_{1}=constant$$

$$\dot{\lambda _{2}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{2}} =-\lambda _{1},so   \lambda _{2} = -c_{1}x+c_{2}$$

$$\dot{\lambda _{3}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{3}} =0,so   \lambda _{3} = c_{3}=constant$$

$$\dot{\lambda _{4}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{4}} =-\lambda _{3},so   \lambda _{4} = -c_{3}x+c_{4}$$

$$\dot{\lambda _{5}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{5}} =-(\lambda _{2}\frac{20u_{1}}{m}cosx_{5}+\lambda _{4}\frac{20u_{1}}{m}(-sinx_{5})  )$$

I can't solve for $\lambda _{5}$ due to the trigonometric function, which stops me from continuing.

Now, I have come across a Python-based solution [here](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime), which seems to address my problem. However, my task extends beyond simply applying this solution.

My goal is to write a comprehensive report detailing the problem-solving process, implemented either in Python or MATLAB. As I am still in the process of studying optimization control, I suspect that a numerical solution might be more feasible for this problem. But, I am also open to an analytical solution if one exists.

In the course of my research, I've found that most examples in textbooks only address relatively simple optimization problems, like this one:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\dot{x_{1}}=x_{2}  \\\dot{x_{2}}=u\end{matrix}\right.$$

In these cases, the handling of the λ variable is straightforward and does not involve more complex functions like the trigonometric ones that are giving me trouble.

Additionally, I should note that not all variables for this problem have been provided by my professor. I presume this won't significantly impact the solution, as I can designate initial or final values for these variables myself.

Ultimately, the main challenge is dealing with the Hamiltonian function. If I can solve for the value of $\lambda _{5}$ , I should be able to employ the minimum principle and the bang-bang theory to finish the remaining work. Alternatively, I am considering tackling this problem numerically.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or resources that might help me handle these numerical solutions.